# Japanese newbie, Chinese intermediate, how to get started?

Tags: learning, resources

I know mandarin, specifically pinyin tones, strokes writing rules, about 1000 characters. So what'd be a starting point for me with Japanese?

Comment: This type of question [does not fall within the scope of this site](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-and-usage/798#798).

Comment: That being said, you may want to look at the [meta post for learning resources](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese). 
Knowledge of Chinese may come in handy for learning kanji, but Japanese and Chinese are very different languages. Basically, you will have to start from the beginning.

Comment: At the beginning :) Chinese is to Japanese as Latin is to English. Knowing it will help you guess some root words, but they're otherwise compleatly different. If you run into any specific questions, we're always happy to help here!